# Why are instances created using a 'literal syntax' known as 'literals'?

Tags: objective-c, terminology, literals, objective-c-literals

Something that is bothering me is why the term 'literal' is used to refer to instances of classes like `NSString` and `NSArray`. I had only seen the term used in reference to `NSString` and being naive I thought it had something to do with it 'literally' being a string, that is between quotation markers. Sorry if that sounds pathetic, but that was how I had been thinking about it.

Then today I learned that certain instances of `NSArray` can also be referred to as literal instances, i.e. an instance of the class created using a 'literal syntax'.

Comment: literal = hard-coded into the code at compilation time. E. g.: `@[ @"foo", @"bar" ]` is an array literal. Compare that with something you obtain dynamically, at run-time (e. g. the result of parsing some JSON, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Linuxios notes, literal syntaxes are built into the language. They're broader than you think, though. A literal just means that an actual value is encoded in the source. So there are quite a few literal syntaxes in ObjC. For example:

- `1` - int
- `1.0` - double
- `1.0f` - float
- `"a"` - C-string
- `@"a"` - NSString
- `@[]` - NSArray
- `^{}` - function

Yeah, blocks are just function literals. They are an anonymous value that is assignable to a symbol name (such as a variable or constant).

Generally speaking, literals can be stored in the text segment and be computed at compile time (rather than at run time). If I remember correctly, array literals are currently expanded into the equivalent code and evaluated at runtime, but `@"..."` string literals are encoded into the binary as static data (at least now they are; non-Apple versions of gcc used to encode an actual function call to construct static strings as I remember).

Comment: Yes, `@[...]` is `arrayWithObjects:count:`, and this is the reason you can't use literals other than `NSString`s at the top level of a file.

Comment: Really? Blocks are function literals? I thought that they were fundamentally different at the language level due to C functions not being closures of any kind.

Comment: C functions are a kind of closure. They close over the current lexical scope that they are defined in. So a variable defined in the current file (but outside the function itself) will be closed over, just like in a block. Blocks are closely related to functions in C. I think what you mean is that function *pointers* are not closures of any kind, and I'd agree with that.

Comment: @Linuxios: Blocks are [_implemented_ as a certain interesting kind of struct](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17819142/), but it's fair to say that they are indeed literal functions.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Didn't realize that. It's kind of frightening and awesome that Objective-C is really just some macros and a library for C.

Comment: That's what makes it so much fun, @Linuxios!

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Agreed. It's like Ruby with segmentation faults.

Comment: @RobNapier: Thanks for such a detailed answer. Got it, save for the 'text segment' part! What do you mean by this? Text as opposed to number related data that go into compilation code?

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Top level of the file? :/

Comment: You can't put method/function calls outside the context of a method/function body, @shinnyWhack.

Comment: @shinnyWhack "text segment" is where the code of the program goes in the executable. It's just an old term for that part of the file. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment

Answer (score 2):

A literal syntax or a literal is just an object that was created using a dedicated syntax built into the language instead of using the normal syntax for object creation (whatever that is).

Here I create a literal array:

```
NSArray* a = @[@"Hello", @"World"];
```

Which is, for all intents and purposes equivalent to this:

```
NSArray* a = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Hello", @"World", nil];
```

The first is called a literal because the `@[]` syntax is built into the language for creating arrays, in the same way that the `@"..."` syntax is built in for creating `NSString`s.

Answer (score 1):

> the term 'literal' is used to refer to instances of classes

It's not referring to the instance really; after the object is created, the way it was created doesn't matter:

```
NSArray * thisWasCreatedWithALiteral = @[@1, @2];
NSArray * butWhoCares = thisWasCreatedWithALiteral;
```

The "literal" part is just the special syntax `@[@1, @2]`, and

> it ha[s] something to do with it 'literally' being a string, that is between quotation markers.

is exactly right: this is a **written-out** representation of the array, as opposed to one created with a constructor method like `arrayWithObjects:`