# Is there any issue if local std::function out of its "life"?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c++11, objective-c-blocks, objective-c++

Could you please help to review the below code? is there any issue if a local std::function is out of its "life"? Thanks in advance.

```
class Test {
    public:
    void commit(std::function<void()> func)
    {
        // return immediately
        dispatch_async(conqueue, ^{
            // in order to call func when it is out of "life"
            sleep(5);
            func(); // is there any issue? the func should be invalid at this moment?
        });
    }

    void test() {
        std::string name = "test";
        std::function<void()> func = [name, this] () {
            printf("%lx %s\n", &name, name.c_str());
            std::cout << "callback"<<std::endl;
        };
        // async
        commit(func);
    }
    //...
};
```

Comment: Do you have any specific problem with it? Should be fine IMO.

Comment: I think the func should be invalid due to the test is returned? I did not see any problem at runtime coz it's a simple code and the memory is not corrupt even it's invalid? is there any exception in some complicated cases?

Comment: Duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941562/what-is-the-lifetime-of-a-c-lambda-expression . What you need to be careful about is the lifetime of any captured values in your lambda, unless those are captured by value (as you did).

Comment: I'm not too sure about `std::function` (or C++ class types in general), but this might apply: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40315949/5754656

Comment: What's that `^{...}` thing? That's not in the standard C++.

Comment: I guess it depends on `dispatch_async` and this `^{}` construct. Is this C++-CLI? Please tag it if so (or wherever these things actually are).

Comment: yes, it's objective-c.

Comment: Thanks,  πάντα ῥεῖ. if the captured values are deep copied, it should be safe, right? it should have a problem if just use the reference?

Comment: @android2test Yes, exactly. `this` might be a problem though, if the class is destructed before the async function call completes. You'll need to use a `std::mutex` or a similar synchronization mechanism to prevent that. (BTW if you want to ping me, put a `@` as prefix before my nickname, otherwise I'll not be noticed in my inbox)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @πάντα ῥεῖ.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I ran some tests and have changed my view on this.  The code is safe because `func` is captured by value (i.e. the block inherits a copy).

I proved this to myself with the following test program (you will need MacOS to run this):

```
// clang block_test.mm -lc++

#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dispatch/dispatch.h>

struct Captured
{
    Captured () {}
    Captured (const Captured &c) { std::cout << "Copy constructor\n"; }
    void Foo () const { std::cout << "Foo\n"; }
};

int main ()
{
    Captured c;

    // return immediately
    dispatch_async (dispatch_get_global_queue (DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),
    ^{
        sleep(5);
        c.Foo ();
     });
    
    sleep (10);
};
```

Output:

```
Copy constructor
Copy constructor
Foo
```

I'm not sure why the copy constructor is called twice though.  Ask Apple.

**Update:** There's a good writeup on working with blocks [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html).  That's what that funny 'hat' syntax is.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I am not sure whether the func will be copied to block of dispatch_async or not?

Comment: Ah, that's a good point.  Neither am I.  You could test that with a simple class who's copy constructor outputs something to `cout`.

Comment: @PaulSanders Note that OP also captured `this` in their example. This needs to be handled with care if the lambda is executed asynchonously (see my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64432753/is-there-any-issue-if-local-stdfunction-out-of-its-life#comment113934840_64432753) please).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, but I think he was more concerned about capturing `func` in the block.

Comment: @paul That's what's covered in the dupe I proposed.

Answer (score 0):

It's safe. Apple "Blocks" capture non-`__block` variables by value, so the block contains a copy of the `std::function` inside it, so the lifetime of the block's copy of the variable is the same as the block itself.

(P.S. Even if the variable was declared `__block`, it would still be safe. Blocks capture `__block` variables kind of "by reference", in that multiple blocks, as well as the original function scope, share the state of the variable. However, the underlying mechanism of `__block` ensures that the variable is moved to the heap if it is used by a block that outlives the function's scope. So for a `__block` variable, its lifetime lasts until all blocks that captured it have been destroyed.)