# Performance Differences Capturing External Variables in Blocks via __block vs Not

Tags: objective-c, performance, objective-c-blocks

When bringing externally declared variables into a block...

Using the `__block` directive captures a variable by reference...

> Variables local to the enclosing lexical scope declared with the __block storage modifier are provided by reference and so are mutable.
>   Any changes are reflected in the enclosing lexical scope, including any other blocks defined within the same enclosing lexical scope.

Without the variable is captured by value...

> Local variables declared within the lexical scope of the block, which behave exactly like local variables in a function.
>   Each invocation of the block provides a new copy of that variable. These variables can in turn be used as const or by-reference variables in blocks enclosed within the block.

I've heard it said that using the __block is less efficient, but how is this possible? Won't you always avoid a costly copy?

Comment: Related: [How does a block capture the variables outside of its enclosing scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813870/how-does-a-block-capture-the-variables-outside-of-its-enclosing-scope/17819142#17819142)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Won't you always avoid a costly copy?

No, this is not costly, because solely the *variable* is copied. The variable is a reference to an object, therefore typically a single machine word.

The referred object itself is not copied.

Comment: LOL i always forget this. Apple makes it so easy to. vs when writing C++.

Answer (score 3):

The copy won't be costly unless the variable type is a huge struct or huge C++ class.

Even if you declare it as `__block`, it is initially stored on the stack (like a local variable) but it will get moved to the heap if any block that uses it is copied, and this move will involve a copy of the variable anyway.